# How can i get session value dynamic another url in same page header.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I want to communicate with the session on two pages that I dynamically create on a Wordpress theme. I do this on a common header.php file, but I can't get the session value I sent from one page on the other. Could you help?

```
$pageName = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($pageName == "/test/"){

    $_SESSION["1cKullaniciLogin"] = "TEST DENEME";

    header("Location: /faaliyet-raporlarimiz/");
    exit();
}

if($pageName == "/faaliyet-raporlarimiz/"){

    if(ISSET($_SESSION["1cKullaniciLogin"]))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: /test/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you start the PHP session before your given code?

Comment: yes, i did. but i think my problem is; cache system because; it works firstly however doesnt work secondly

Comment: That could be the culprit. Test your code by disabling the caching. It is better to follow PSR guideline while coding.

Comment: how can i disable the caching in wordpress?